# Angular 4 dynamic plugin component from lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular-router

I have an angular 4 system that allows plugin modules (loaded with `systemjs`). They are loaded and compiled "manually", creating a `NgModuleFactory` for each module. This is done when the application starts, because I need to build up a main menu, and a settings component dynamically. I also build the routes dynamically in this way, by passing the `NgModuleFactory` instance to the `loadChildren` member of the route.

In these plugin modules, some components are defined, that in the main app will be used to build up the settings component. So the root settings component contains controls from the plugin modules. And this is done dynamically at load time, by using the `NgModuleFactory`, creating a `NgModuleRef`, and using the instance property to get the instance of the ngmodule, and then the injector that created at this point. The problem is that services defined in these plugin modules, that should be singletons, are instantiated twice. As far as I understand, the router creates its own `NgModuleRef`, so probably its own injector, so at this point there are two different injectors that each will instantiate a service.

Did anybody have solved something like that before? I would guess there are two possibilities (in theory):

- Forcing somehow the router to reuse the `NgModuleRef` that I previously created. I don't know if this is possible. (Later edit) I actually found a method, looking through angular router code. It seems that the `NgModuleRef` is cached in the `_loadedConfig` property in the `Route` itself. So when creating the routes, and overriding them, I provide also this property. So when the angular normal routing mechanism is triggered, angular router checks this value, and doesn't create a new `NgModuleRef` and also not a new Injector. It seems to be a hack, since `_loadedConfig` was meant only for internal use.
- Trying somehow to force the router to create the `NgModuleRef` (and injector) somehow, and try to reuse the same things (injector, `NgModuleRef`) when creating the settings components dynamically. Also I'm not sure how to do that.

Or maybe there is another way to achieve this?